# OpenCV - Cropping non rectangular region from image using C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

How can I crop a non rectangular region from image?

Imagine I have four points and I want to crop it, this shape wouldn't be a triangle somehow!

For example I have the following image :

[image]

and I want to crop  this from image :

[image]

How can I do this?
regards..

Comment: How do you want to decide on the region to crop? Do you want to just always blindly make that crop you demonstrated? Or do you want a diamond shape all the time? In general you can use OpenCV's bitwise_and function to mask off part of the image, but then generating the mask is what requires more details.

Comment: the region would be none constant I mean it would be in any shape but always it has 4 corners

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The procedure for cropping an arbitrary quadrilateral (or any polygon for that matter) part of an image is summed us as:

- Generate a "mask". The mask is black where you want to keep the image, and white where you don't want to keep it
- Compute the "bitwise_and" between your input image and the mask

So, lets assume you have an image. Throughout this I'll use an image size of 30x30 for simplicity, you can change this to suit your use case.

```
cv::Mat source_image = cv::imread("filename.txt");
```

And you have four points you want to use as the corners:

```
cv::Point corners[1][4];
corners[0][0] = Point( 10, 10 );
corners[0][1] = Point( 20, 20 );
corners[0][2] = Point( 30, 10 );
corners[0][3] = Point( 20, 10 );
const Point* corner_list[1] = { corners[0] };
```

You can use the function [`cv::fillPoly`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#fillpoly) to draw this shape on a mask:

```
int num_points = 4;
int num_polygons = 1;
int line_type = 8;
cv::Mat mask(30,30,CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0,0,0));
cv::fillPoly( mask, corner_list, &num_points, num_polygons, cv::Scalar( 255, 255, 255 ),  line_type);
```

Then simply compute the bitwise_and of the image and mask:

```
cv::Mat result;
cv::bitwise_and(source_image, mask, result);
```

`result` now has the cropped image in it. If you want the edges to end up white instead of black you could instead do:

```
cv::Mat result_white(30,30,CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(255,255,255));
cv::bitwise_and(source_image, mask, result_white, mask);
```

In this case we use `bitwise_and`'s mask parameter to only do the bitwise_and inside the mask. See [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/basic_geometric_drawing/basic_geometric_drawing.html) for more information and links to all the functions I mentioned.

Comment: I got "no matching function 'fillPoly' error :( please help me: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45441744/3162918

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that error: I've updated my answer. I needed to pass num_points as a pointer.

Comment: and what is your "white" variable in the second bitwise_and case?

Comment: it should be cv::bitwise_and(source_image, mask, result_white, mask);

Comment: @bendaf I hadn't originally declared the `white` variable, I updated the answer to declare it (thanks for pointing that out). I don't think your recommended solution works, though: that will make the edges black. The trick here is to AND the image with an already white image just within the mask.

Comment: I did try that out and it worked. I think the content of the first two input matters only in the place of the mask, and the other places will stay white in the result_white image.

Comment: @bendaf ah okay, you're right, thanks for pointing that out. I think when I wrote the example code I had first done it the way I described, then did it your way, but my answer ended up being a hybrid of the two. I have fixed the answer per your recommendation.

Comment: `cv::bitwise_and` with `result_white` gives an opencv exception

Comment: @IterAtor you should post that as a separate question, including the code you have written.

Answer (score 1):

You may use cv::Mat::copyTo() like this:

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("image.jpeg");
// note mask may be single channel, even if img is multichannel
cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8UC1);
// fill mask with nonzero values, e.g. as Tim suggests
// cv::fillPoly(...)
cv::Mat result(img.size(), img.type(), cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255));
img.copyTo(result, mask);
```