# openCV no matching function fillPoly

Tags: c++, opencv, syntax, no-match

I am trying to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41689827/3162918) answer, but I am getting always error. Please help.

My code:

```
cv::Point corners[1][6];

for (unsigned long j = startIndex; j < startIndex+6; j++) {
  int x = shape.part(j).x(); 
  int y = shape.part(j).y();

  corners[0][j-startIndex] = Point(x, y);
}
const Point* corner_list[1] = {corners[0]};

cv::Mat mask(image.rows, image.cols, CV_8UC2);
cv::fillPoly(mask, corner_list, 6, 1, cv::Scalar(255), 8);
cv::Mat result(image.size(), image.type(), cv::Scalar(0,0,0));
image.copyTo(result, mask);
```

Here is my error:

```
jni/jni_detections/jni_face_det.cpp:121:5: error: no matching function for call to 'fillPoly'
    cv::fillPoly( mask, corner_list, num_points, num_polygons, cv::Scalar( 255, 255, 255 ),  line_type);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~ 
/home/feli/Development/android/test/dlib/dlib-android/third_party/opencv/jni/include/opencv2/imgproc.hpp:3987:17: note: 
      candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'const int *' for 3rd argument; take the address of
      the argument with & CV_EXPORTS void fillPoly(Mat& img, const Point** pts,
                                          ^ 
/home/feli/Development/android/test/dlib/dlib-android/third_party/opencv/jni/include/opencv2/imgproc.hpp:4005:19: note: 
      candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const Point *[1]' to 'const cv::_InputArray' for 2nd argument 
CV_EXPORTS_W void fillPoly(InputOutputArray img, InputArrayOfArrays pts,
                  ^
```

My OpenCV version is 3.1.0

Comment: Looks like you need to change `cv::Scalar(255)` to `cv::Scalar(255,255,255)`

Comment: Or Scalar::all(255).

Comment: "no known conversion from 'int' to 'const int *' for 3rd argument" -- the 3rd argument needs to be a pointer to integer, not an integer constant as you have it. | Also `CV_8UC2` looks like a rather odd for a mask. Why 2 channels?

Comment: @bandaf I have updated my answer in the other question: there was an error in it. The "numPoints" parameter (6 in your example) should be a pointer. See my answer in your first link for an example.

Comment: That was the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to pass the numPoints parameter's pointer like this:

```
int num_points = 6;
cv::fillPoly(mask, corner_list, &num_points, 1, cv::Scalar(255), 8);
```

Thanks @Tim Sweet

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to change

```
cv::Scalar(255)
```

to

```
cv::Scalar(255,255,255)
```

Comment: Typo in your answer. It should `cv::Scalar(255,255,255)` instead of `cv:Scalar(255,255,255)`

Comment: This sort of thing wouldn't cause a compilation error the OP is getting. Besides that, `mask` is currently (for some unknown reason) a 2 channel image, so this isn't really much more correct.

Comment: I had to do this also, but not that one caused the build error